# Text is not shown when page rendered but shown if I change layout from devtools afterwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, fonts

Working on angular2 project and have issues with text rendering. Nor placeholder nor input value are shown in Chrome(54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)) until I go to devtools and do any random change which forces layout to rerender. After that everything is perfect. Have no idea where to dig.

to reproduce: [ordentravel.ru](http://ordentravel.ru), then click on the first link in top right corner and you will see 2 empty inputs. That are exactly the input fields I described above.

[image]

**UPDATE:** issue with the fonts. When I use Arial everything fine. Once I start using Lifehack issue appears. That is how I define font in sass:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lifehack Sans Regular';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Lifehack Sans Regular.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
      url('/assets/fonts/Lifehack Sans Regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('/assets/fonts/Lifehack Sans Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('/assets/fonts/Lifehack Sans Regular.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

$font-style-regular: Lifehack Sans Regular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Comment: do  you add some codes?

Comment: Hi, @dreamhunter, what do you mean?

Comment: please add some code,without your code we can just predict your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was I defined same `font-face` several times in my styles.

I added it to `app.component.scss` and then imported this file in several other sass files duplicating the `font-face` definition.